# Try...catch returning nothing but code is still breaking

Tags: c#, try-catch

UPDATE: So this code is collection a SQL Query into a DataSet prior to this method.  This data set is then dropped into excel in the corresponding tab at a specific cell address(which is loaded from the form)  but the code below is the exporting to excel method.  I am getting the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in SQUiRE (Sql QUery REtriever) v1.exe
```

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I have been tracking this for a while and thought I fixed it, but my solution was a false positive.  So I am using a try...catch block that is breaking but not returning anything.  Let me know if you all see anything that I am missing.  I usually break on this line (templateSheet = templateBook.Sheets[tabName];) and on the same tabName.  The tab is not locked or restricted so It can be written to and works more than half of the time.

```
public void ExportToExcel(DataSet dataSet, Excel.Workbook templateBook, int i, int h, Excel.Application excelApp) //string filePath, 
    {
        try
        {

            lock (this.GetType())
            {
                Excel.Worksheet templateSheet;

                //check to see if the template is already open, if its not then open it,
                //if it is then bind it to work with it
                //if (!fileOpenTest)
                //{ templateBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath); }
                //else
                //{ templateBook = (Excel.Workbook)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(filePath); }


                //Grabs the name of the tab to dump the data into from the "Query Dumps" Tab
                string tabName = lstQueryDumpSheet.Items[i].ToString();
                templateSheet = templateBook.Sheets[tabName];                   

                // Copy DataTable
                foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
                {
                    // Copy the DataTable to an object array
                    object[,] rawData = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count];

                    // Copy the values to the object array
                    for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
                        { rawData[row, col] = dt.Rows[row].ItemArray[col]; }
                    }

                    // Calculate the final column letter
                    string finalColLetter = string.Empty;
                    string colCharset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                    int colCharsetLen = 26;

                    if (dt.Columns.Count > colCharsetLen)
                    { finalColLetter = colCharset.Substring((dt.Columns.Count - 1) / colCharsetLen - 1, 1); }

                    finalColLetter += colCharset.Substring((dt.Columns.Count - 1) % colCharsetLen, 1);

                    /*Grabs the full cell address from the "Query Dump" sheet, splits on the '=' and
                     *pulls out only the cell address (i.e., "address=a3" becomes "a3")*/
                    string dumpCellString = lstQueryDumpText.Items[i].ToString();
                    string dumpCell = dumpCellString.Split('=').Last();

                    /*Refers to the range in which we are dumping the DataSet.  The upper right hand cell is
                     *defined by 'dumpCell'and the bottom right cell is defined by the final column letter 
                     *and the count of rows.*/
                    string firstRef = "";
                    string baseRow = "";

                    //Determines if the column is one letter or two and handles them accordingly
                    if (char.IsLetter(dumpCell, 1))
                    {
                        char[] createCellRef = dumpCell.ToCharArray();
                        firstRef = createCellRef[0].ToString() + createCellRef[1].ToString();

                        for (int z = 2; z < createCellRef.Count(); z++)
                        { baseRow = baseRow + createCellRef[z].ToString(); }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        char[] createCellRef = dumpCell.ToCharArray();
                        firstRef = createCellRef[0].ToString();

                        for (int z = 1; z < createCellRef.Count(); z++)
                        { baseRow = baseRow + createCellRef[z].ToString(); }
                    }

                    int baseRowInt = Convert.ToInt32(baseRow);
                    int startingCol = ColumnLetterToColumnIndex(firstRef);
                    int endingCol = ColumnLetterToColumnIndex(finalColLetter);
                    int finalCol = startingCol + endingCol;
                    string endCol = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(finalCol - 1);
                    int endRow = (baseRowInt + (dt.Rows.Count - 1));
                    string cellCheck = endCol + endRow;
                    string excelRange;

                    if (dumpCell.ToUpper() == cellCheck.ToUpper())
                    { excelRange = string.Format(dumpCell + ":" + dumpCell); }
                    else
                    { excelRange = string.Format(dumpCell + ":{0}{1}", endCol, endRow); }

                    //Dumps the cells into the range on Excel as defined above
                    templateSheet.get_Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData;

                    /*Check to see if all the SQL queries have been run from 
                    if (i == lstSqlAddress.Items.Count - 1)
                    {
                        //Turn Auto Calc back on
                        excelApp.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic;

                        /*Run through the value save sheet array then grab the address from the corresponding list 
                         *place in the address array.  If the address reads "whole sheet" then save the whole page,
                         *else set the addresses range and value save that.

                        for (int y = 0; y < lstSaveSheet.Items.Count; y++)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Save Sheet: " + lstSaveSheet.Items[y] + "\n" + "Save Address: " + lstSaveRange.Items[y]);
                        }*/

                        //run the macro to hide the unused columns
                        excelApp.Run("ReportMakerExecute");

                        //save excel file as hospital name and move onto the next
                        SaveTemplateAs(templateBook, h);                            
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a better description of what is not working and of what you are trying to accomplish. Right now it is a hunk of code with little context and that no one is going to read.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I have updated with a bit more information.  Hope that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by the block not returning anything?

Comment: @MatiCicero Well I have the try..catch around the entire block that the code break in.  When it breaks I expect it the throw a MesssageBox with the exception string, but i just get the typical break message

Comment: @MatiCicero  I did, with the same result I am having now.

Comment: @JohnColeman `"When it breaks I expect it to throw a MessageBox with the exception string"`, why whould it break if you are catching the exception? Also, what do you mean by `typical break message`?

Comment: @MatiCicero ok this may be where I am hitting the issue.  I am trying to capture exactly what the issue is.  I am new to C#, so I may be explaining it wrong.  I am fluent in VBA, I was trying to make something similar to On error goto errorhandler..and the error handler would capture the error message and spit out what is going on.  The exception I am getting makes little or no sense to me and I am having trouble pinpointing what is causing it to happen.  I am trying to zero in on the cause.

Comment: Are you running the program in Visual Studio in debug mode?  If so, go to Debug > Exceptions...  and see if VS is set to break on all exceptions or just those that are unhandled.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway everything is still in default mode.  I have not changed anything with Debug > Exceptions